# CPU frequency scaling on Ubuntu and Windows

Tags: windows, cpu

Linux reports my CPU's maximum frequency as 2.40 GHz and min as 1.2 GHz. Windows 8's Task Manager shows the CPU frequency going above 3.0 GHz or below 1.0 GHz on occasion, according to usage. This is something I have noticed in 12.10, 13.04, and 13.10, as well as Arch Linux.

I have a 3rd-gen Corei7-3630QM CPU @2.40 GHz, according to `lshw -c cpu`.
Anybody know how Windows gets to the larger range of frequencies?
What will happen if I force set the maximum and minimums to more extreme values, by doing something like:

```
for file in /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu*/cpufreq/scaling_max_freq
do
      echo 3001000 > $file
done
```

Right now the exact maximum frequency in all /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu*/cpufreq/scaling_max_freq files is 2401000.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is Intel Turbo Boost in action. One of the cores can go higher freq. when it is necessary and the other go low. Like for example : you have a process, that uses 70% of only one core of CPU, so you processor raises this core' frequency and makes other cores lower theirs in order to stay in TDP - not to overheat. I am not sure if it is implemented on OS level, or on hardware level. But anyway, do not worry, if you try to set a higher or lower range of frequencies on Linux- you WILL NOT FRY your CPU. No way  there are safeties built in. You can't just make a mobile CPU run faster than it can. It is not a CORE-I7 EXTREME series